# Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement'

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, openlayers-3

I tried to print a map using a click button but  I got this error :

> Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases
>   may not be exported

I searched some some solutions like insert this in the code :

```
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
```

here the code i used :

```
ol.control.Print = function(opt_options) {

    var options = opt_options || {};
    var _this = this;
    var dataURL;

    var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    controlDiv.className = options.className || 'ol-print ol-unselectable ol-control';

    var printButton = document.createElement('button');
    printButton.textContent = options.label || '';
    printButton.title = options.tipLabel || 'Print map';
    printButton.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        _this.getMap().once('postcompose', function(evt) {
            var canvas = evt.context.canvas;
            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        });
        _this.getMap().renderSync();
        window.open(dataURL, '_blank').print();
        dataURL = null;
    });

    controlDiv.appendChild(printButton);

    ol.control.Control.call(this, {
        element: controlDiv,
        target: options.target
    });
};


ol.inherits(ol.control.Print, ol.control.Control);
```